# Registro com Arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Como saber se existe um Registro (struct) salvo em alguma posição em um arquivo em C ?

Para o `struct`:

```
typedef struct Registro
{
     int chave;
     char caracteres[20];
     int idade;
     int prox;
     bool contem;
} Registro;
```

Por exemplo:

```
fseek(fl,0*sizeof(Registro),SEEK_SET);
fread(&registro,sizeof(Registro),1,fl);
```

As informações da posição 0 foram carregadas em `registro`. Como saber se ele existe ?

Comment: Qual a estrutura do `Registro`?

Comment: typedef struct Registro{
 int chave;
 char caracteres[20];
 int idade;
 int prox;
 bool contem;
}Registro;

Comment: Edite sua pergunta para colocar este complemento, assim ela fica mais organizada.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!!

Answer (score 2):

Como assim, "se ele existe"????

Se o resultado do `fread()` tiver sido 1, o objecto `registro` foi preenchido com informacoes do *stream*; se o resultado tiver sido 0 houve um erro que podes determinar atraves de `errno`

```
if (fread(&registro, sizeof (Registro), 1, fl) == 0) {
    perror("Registro");
    // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Eu preciso verificar nas posições se já existe algum registro salvo.. Então desse jeito ai funciona ?

Comment: O `fread()` devolve o numero de items lidos, ou `0` em caso de erro. Se o conteudo do ficheiro nao for compativel com a estrutura, o `fread()` nao vai assinalar erro, mas os valores obtidos serao lixo

Comment: E como faço para deletar um registro ? Existe alguma função ?

Comment: Nao ha funcao propria para apagar registo. O usual e escrever um ficheiro novo, depois apagar o antigo e mudar o nome ao novo

Answer (score 2):

Além da verificação que o @pmg apresentou, eu recomendaria fazer uma verificação dos dados lidos, para ter certeza de que são o que você espera e ter certeza de que o `Registro` existe.

Por exemplo, se você criar um arquivo `arquivo.dat` preenchido assim:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

E, depois, ler ele como um `Registro`, seu programa funcionará perfeitamente. O arquivo existe, possui conteúdo suficiente para preencher o `sizeof(Registro)` mas o conteúdo não é de um `Registro` (isso seria um falso positivo no seu programa):

```
caracteres: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa☻
chave: 1633771873
contem: 1633771873
idade: 1633771873
prox: 1633771873
```

Comment: Mas não terá inserção dessa maneira no arquivo. Somente via código mesmo, usando o fwrite(). Sendo assim, posso ficar despreocupado ?

Comment: Foi só para exemplo. De qualquer forma, isso não impede do usuário editar o arquivo e alterá-lo de forma indevida ou mesmo de abrir o arquivo errado.

Answer (score 0):

Por exemplo digamos que o arquivo foi criado dessa forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Registro
{
 int chave;
 char caracteres[20];
 int idade;
 int prox;
 bool contem;
} Registro;

int main(){
Registro registro = {0,"",0,0,false};

FILE *fPtr;
if((fPtr = fopen("arquivo.dat","wb")) == NULL){
    printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
}
else{
     /* Inicializa dez campos "vazios" no arquivo,sem dados de usuario */
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
         fwrite(&registro,sizeof(Registro),1,fPtr);
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
 }

return 0;
}
```

Podemos verificar se há campos "vazios" fazendo o seguinte:

```
int main(){

Registro registro = {0,"",0,0,false};

FILE *fPtr;
if((fPtr = fopen("arquivo.dat","rb")) == NULL){
    printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
}
else{
    fseek(fPtr,0*sizeof(Registro),SEEK_SET);
    fread(&registro,sizeof(Registro),1,fPtr);

    if(registro.chave == 0 && strcmp(registro.caracteres,"") == 0){
        printf("Esse campo esta vazio!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Esse campo contem dados!\n");
    }
    fclose(fPtr);

 }
return 0;
}
```